# How to select automatically specific columns from df.columns for table on plotly.go.Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I am creating a table which is a `plotly go.Figure()` object and I am trying to display only a few columns headers from my `df`.

```
fig_positions = go.Figure(data=go.Table(
            header=dict(values=[df.columns[['Block Number', 'Base Token']]]
)))
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

If I use `df.columns` instead, it creates the table with all `df` columns.

How can I create a table with `plotly.go.Figure()` wit selected column headers without manually specifying each one like `(df['Block Number'], df['Base Token'], ...)`

Comment: Have you looked at this link https://plotly.com/python/table/? because you should use cells.

Comment: I have and am using cells. My cells manually describe each column. `df['Block Number'], df['Base Token']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are header and cells and you should define each one as follows:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=list(df.columns)),
    cells=dict(values=[df.col1, df.col2, df.col3, df.col4])
])
```

You can create your list automatically with specific columns as follows:

```
headers=dict(values=[df.columns[col] for col in [1,3,4]])
cells=dict(values=[df.iloc[:,col] for col in [1,3,4]])
```

Here I only create a table with columns indexed by 1, 3, and 4.

Comment: Getting now the error: `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 10 were indexed` for 
`cells=dict(values=[df.iloc[:, col] for col in df.columns[0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]`.

Comment: Please read thoroughly my solution, there is no `df.columns` after `for`.